# Dynamically loading a view, telerik mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm trying to load a page using `$.ajax()`.
I have view **person** with the actions: **Index**, **Create**, **Delete**.
The page **Create**, has a **Grid of Telerik MVC**.
The problem occurs when I'm on page **Index** and **load** the page **Create** with an **ajax call** to replace the contents of the current page.
The page is fully loaded but the **grid does not work**, `$('#gridname').data('tGrid')` returns **undefined**.

A example of the javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Person/Create',
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#main').html($(data).fadeIn(fade));
    }
});
```

Thank's

Comment: If you look in devtools can you see the presence of `gridName` in the HTML?

Comment: yes, the name is there,
when the page 'Create' is loaded the 'datagrid' works perfectly, but when loaded via ajax call, not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this problem many times. The issue is that when a Telerik control on a partial view is rendered, it adds a `script` tag with the JavaScript needed to initialize the control. jQuery strips that `script` tag out if you use `$.ajax`. Try the following:

```
$('#main').load('/Person/Create');
```

`jQuery.load` does not string out the `script` tag.

EDIT:

Looks like there's more to it than just `load`. Telerik has an article about it here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/using-with-partial-views-loaded-via-ajax.html

Basically, you need to make sure the Telerik scripts are referenced in the page (since they won't be automatically added) and you must use ajax to bind the data.

Comment: When the Grid is rendered on a page, Telerik adds javascript to the jQuery(document).ready() function to create the $('#Grid').data('tGrid') object.
This is the problem, i can't get the data('tGrid'). tks

Comment: So, did you try using `jQuery.load`?